# How to add new keys into an NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, key, nsmutabledictionary

I have a plist which is to be populated with arrays. But I need a header for these arrays and the only kind I know of are keys. I've searched this site but I cannot find the answer I am looking for. Do you have any chance that you might know how?

Comment: I don't get it, try to make your question a little bit clearer. I assume you aren't asking for `[dictionary setValue:bar forKey:@"Foo"];`

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear about "i need a header for these arrays and the only kind i know of are keys". Do you want a string identifier for each array?

Answer (score 2):

Just use an NSMutableArray to store your arrays and use their indexes as your headers.  Store them using:

```
[myMutableArray insertObject:myObject atIndex:myIndex];
```